# Can not display a SVG Graphic with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

how can i display a svg graphics using thymeleaf in a html fragment?

following snippets are not working:

```
<img th:src="@{vector.svg}">

<svg width="300px" height="300px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" th:src="@{vector.svg}>
```

the location of the svg graphics are "static/images/vector.svg"

also tried th:data

I'm using thymeleaf 3 with Spring boot 4 and flying saucer.

Comment: It's the same as any other `<img />`, there is nothing special about svg and thymeleaf.  You need to find the correct url to view your image in the browser (e.g. http://localhost/context/vector.svg), and then create the url expression to point to it.  You've not provided enough details to fix this.

Comment: Well I forgot to say: I use Thymeleaf with flying saucer.